# Kubernetes http requests from frontend to backend service

Tags: kubernetes

I'm not sure if I ask this question here, but I need some clarification I have a Kubernetes cluster and I am wondering since the frontend runs on the client's web browser. Am I able to only expose the API internally and still make HTTP requests to it from the client or am I only able to expose the service using the node port, ingress, and load balancer which exposes it to the internet?

Thanks in advance for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expose it to the frontend via an ingress and also (at the same time) internally for other services/pods/containers you have running inside the cluster, it all depends on how you configure it.

Assuming you only want it to run internally, all you have to do is not create an ingress. If you want to expose it, then do create the ingress. In both cases you should always create the 'service' as that's what exposes your pods's code to the cluster (inside and outside via ingress).

Service: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Ingress: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Hope that clarifies it!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so say in my angular frontend I make a http request to http://backend and my api that has an internal service called backend  do I use an ingress rewrite rule to connect it to the backend service without having to expose it externally?

Comment: If you have an Angular frontend, you have to expose it externally, as Angular runs on the browser, it needs an HTTPS endpoint to connect to the API, and that is achieved by creating the ingress and the service. If you do not want to expose your backend, you would have to use a frontend that runs on the server, such as ASP.NET, Blazor Server, PHP, etc, not a frontend system such as Angular. In that case your frontend connects to the service internally since that traffic does not leave the server.